# ASP.NET Core application that references a project in another Git repository

Tags: .net, azure, github, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a solution that consists of three ASP.NET Core MVC applications, and an ASP.NET Core library that has some logic that are shared by the three MVC applications. Each of the applications and the library are their own Git repository.

Now, I'm trying to deploy one of the MVC applications to Azure, and while deploying, it fails with the following error log (only showing the last part here where the error occurs)

```
Installing System.Security.Cryptography.Cng 4.2.0.
Installing System.Security.Cryptography.Csp 4.0.0.
Installing Microsoft.NETCore.Windows.ApiSets 1.0.1.
Committing restore...
Writing lock file to disk. Path: D:\home\site\repository\project.lock.json
D:\home\site\repository\project.json
Restore failed in 55782ms.

NuGet Config files used:
  C:\DWASFiles\Sites\#1cerebro-lantern\AppData\NuGet\NuGet.Config
Errors in D:\home\site\repository\project.json

Feeds used:
  Unable to resolve 'Telepathy (>= 1.0.0)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0'.
  https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json

Installed:
  192 package(s) to D:\home\site\repository\project.json
Failed exitCode=1, command=nuget.exe restore -packagesavemode nuspec
An error has occurred during web site deployment.
Errors in D:\home\site\repository\project.json\r\n    Unable to resolve
'Telepathy (>= 1.0.0)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0'.\r\nD:\Program Files
(x86)\SiteExtensions\Kudu\59.51212.2600\bin\Scripts\starter.cmd 
"D:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd"
```

I understand that it fails because it can't resolve `Telepathy` (this is the Library that lives in another repository), but I'm not clear on how to solve this.

All the three MVC apps use the same library, and I would rather keep it in it's own Git repository, but I'm not clear on how I would get this to find my library in a good way.

Making it a proper NuGet library also seems bad since it's very specific to my application, and will be of no use to anyone else. Is there another solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NuGet is the right solution here. Here's what I've done successfully:

1. Use `dotnet pack` to create NuGet artifacts for your shared library project. You'll want to pay attention to how you version it, of course. Semantic versioning is recommended.
2. Upload the NuGet packages to [MyGet](http://myget.org/), Visual Studio Team Services, or [your own NuGet server](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToHostYourOwnNuGetServerAndPackageFeed.aspx).
3. Add the appropriate feed to your ASP.NET Core MVC projects (via `nuget.config`) and reference the package like any other NuGet package. The package restore process locally (or on Azure) will understand how to get the package, as long as your NuGet server is accessible on the public internet.

This is much cleaner than trying to reference it another way, and you don't have to worry about putting a private package out on nuget.org.

Comment: This seems like a clean solution, and I'm almost there I think. I have managed to create the package in MyGet and reference it in my project, and it works fine locally. However, it still fails when building in Azure. Then I checked the changes done to my project when I added the reference, and the URL to myget is not anywhere to be found inside my project. So I don't really understand how Azure would be able to figure out where to find the package. Is this something I need to set up in Azure somewhere?

Comment: That got solved by adding a nuget.config file, so now it works perfectly. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @ØyvindBråthen Sorry, should have mentioned that. Edited. Glad you got it working!

Comment: No problem. You got me far enough in the right direction :)